# Only execute something if multiple things have been fully executed

Tags: jquery

Let's say I want something only to be executed when one thing has been fully executed I do the following:

```
$('#content-1').fadeIn(function() {
   $("menue").slideUp();
});
```

But what if something should be only be executed if multiple things that have different actions have been fully executed? Like this:

```
$('#content-1').fadeIn();
$('#content-2').fadeOut();
function() {
    $("menue").slideUp();
}
```

How do I do this without separate and repeat?

Comment: Use the `callback` to set flags and use `setInterval` to check the flags in intervals

Comment: Could you state an example, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

You can use `promise()` and `done()` methods:

```
$('#go').click(function () {
    $('#content-1').fadeIn(1000);
    $('#content-2').fadeOut(5000);
    $('#content-1, #content-2').promise().done(function(){
        $("#menu").slideUp();
    })
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cNXvD/3/)

Comment: Oh, wow, does `queue` really work this way on groups of elements? Now I'm kinda interested in testing it out…

Comment: Hm. If we're looking at a general case in which the animations have different durations, [it doesn't seem to work as expected](http://jsfiddle.net/cNXvD/): the callback fires after *each* animation, rather than once after all are complete. Here, though, the different is unnoticeable since the second slideup is ignored, so whatever floats one's boat.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Just the .promise technique I learned from you from the other question :)

Answer (score 2):

You would use callbacks:

```
$('#content-1').fadeIn(500, function() {
    $('#content-2').fadeOut(500, function() {
        $("menue").slideUp();
    });
});
```

Or, if multiple events need to occur simultaneously:

```
var content1_complete = false;
var content2_complete = false;
var callback = function() {
    $("menue").slideUp();
}
$('#content-1').fadeIn(500, function() {
    content1_complete = true;
    if (content1_complete && content2_complete) {
        callback();
    }
}
$('#content-2').fadeIn(500, function() {
    content2_complete = true;
    if (content1_complete && content2_complete) {
        callback();
    }
}
```

But note that if the events take the same amount of time, they should also complete simultaneously, in which case there's no need to have such flags.

Comment: I think the actions on `content-1` and `content-2` are supposed to be happening simultaneously…

Comment: Not if `$('#content-1').fadeIn()` and `$('#content-2').fadeOut()` need to happen together.

Comment: Wow, ok this is very understandable! Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Now that we're on new version of this answer, this is the winner for the general case: clear and to the point :)

Answer (score 1):

We *could* do fancy things with each callback setting some global flag or whatever, but, if the exact durations of the actions are unimportant, the easiest solution by far is to set them to have equal duration, and then put the callback on just one:

```
$('#content-1').fadeIn(400);
$('#content-2').fadeOut(400, function() {
   $("menue").slideUp();
});
```

Since it sounds like you're fading in `content-1` to replace `content-2`, this is probably the most aesthetically pleasing behavior, anyway.

Note that, by default, jQuery assigns all fading animations the same default duration of `400`, so it'd work even without specifying a duration at all — though I like the explicitness of defining them so that future developers don't need to run and check the documentation to make sure. Even so, this should work just fine:

```
$('#content-1').fadeIn();
$('#content-2').fadeOut(function() {
   $("menue").slideUp();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick and detailed answer! For now they really have the same duration. I guess I'll have a look at the global flag technique then for future projects.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
var myanimationstate=0;
$('#content-1').fadeIn(function(){
    if(myanimationstate){
        myslideup();
        myanimationstate=0;
    }else{
        myanimationstate++;
    }
);
$('#content-2').fadeOut(function(){
    if(myanimationstate){
        myslideup();
        myanimationstate=0;
    }else{
        myanimationstate++;
    }
);
function myslideup() {
    $("menue").slideUp();
}
```

Comment: And I know, this is sort of lazy